# Tortoise SVN: Having trouble moving updated code into a new branch

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm very new to tortoise SVN but our company svn policy is as follows, which I'm having difficulty with:

1. Pull application code from what we call "dev/main" (**svn/repo/(app name)/branches/dev/main**) to your local machine.
2. Make your changes locally
3. Once your changes are finished, create a new branch & check your code into that branch
4. Once the change has been approved by our QA team, move your changes in your branch back into the dev/main branch
5. Move your dev/main changes into trunk

So, I can successfully checkout from dev/main to my local computer & make my changes.  However, when I try to move these changes into a new branch, I get a bunch of problems ranging from ancestry errors to tree conflicts.

To change to a new branch, I'm right clicking on the svn folder on my local machine, selecting "Tortoise SVN", then "Switch...".  In the "To Path", I'm entering the svn url of the new branch I just created.  I check the "Ignore Ancestry" checkbox because otherwise, it creates ancestry errors, and then I click "Ok". Unfortunately, I then receive tree conflicts.

Am I doing this wrong?  Should I be taking a different approach to switch from one svn directory to another?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to tell what exactly goes wrong without knowing the exact commands you run. However, it seems to me that the steps in your procedure are wrong.

> 2. Make your changes locally
> 3. Once your changes are finished, create a new branch & check your code into that branch

You need to create a branch first and work on that branch, not on `dev/main/`. As soon as the branch is ready, merge it to `dev/main/`.